# Post status on Google Plus using PHP Curl

Tags: php, curl, google-plus

I have this code for logging into Google using Simple DOM Parser with curl. I've tried to post status on google plus using following code but unable to post on google plus

Any idea on how to solve this?

Here's my code for reference:

```
$clientlogin_url = "https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin";
$clientlogin_post = array(
    "accountType" => "HOSTED_OR_GOOGLE",
    "Email" => "youremail@gmail.com",
    "Passwd" => "yourpassword",
    "service" => "writely",
    "source" => "your application name"
  );

// Initialize the curl object
$curl = curl_init($clientlogin_url);

// Set some options (some for SHTTP)
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $clientlogin_post);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

// Execute
$response = curl_exec($curl);

// Get the Auth string and save it
preg_match("/Auth=([a-z0-9_-]+)/i", $response, $matches);
$auth = $matches[1];

$params['newcontent'] = "Post on Google Plus Test By Me";

$headers = array(
    "Authorization: GoogleLogin auth=" . $auth,
    "GData-Version: 3.0",
);

//  Make the request
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.plus.google.com/');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);

$response = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
```

Thanks For your help and co-operation

Answer (score 2):

There is not a Google+ API to post statuses (unless you are a [Google Apps user](https://developers.google.com/+/domains/)) and [ClientLogin has been deprecated](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/AuthForInstalledApps) and will stop working soon. You're best bet is to look into using something like the [share plugin](https://developers.google.com/+/web/share/).

Answer (score 1):

**In order not show the moved you have to set the agent header like firefox or something else 
example**

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.plus.google.com/');
curl_setopt($curl,"USER_AGENT","firefox my browser");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); //Added here
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); //Added here
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); // Since you got 301 redirect

 $response = curl_exec($curl);
 var_dump($response);// Added here
  curl_close($curl);`enter code here`
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add these two **`cURL`** params here too.

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.plus.google.com/');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); //Added here
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); //Added here
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); // Since you got 301 redirect
```

Also, you are not outputting any response on your code

```
$response = curl_exec($curl);
var_dump($response);// Added here
curl_close($curl);
```

Comment: I haded output too
but such response got
<H1>301 Moved</H1>
The document has moved

Comment: See the edited code, `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);` you need that param for a 301 status code.

Comment: By adding one code it will produce unauthorize like below
<H1>Unauthorized</H1>
<H2>Error 401</H2>

Comment: Can you please check by using above code
I can not trace what wrong with above code
Thanks a lot for help